# Accessing an interface range that spans beyond one stack on a Cisco Switch

Tags: cisco, interface, cli

I want to configure Interfaces 0/3, 1/2 and 1/3 for example. Using `interface range gig 0/3-1/3` did not work, is it simply not possible or is there a different syntax?

EDIT: Of course aside using `interface range gig 0/3 , gig 1/2-3`

Comment: No, and neither does it work with chassis switches where you use slot numbers instead of switch numbers. The stack looks like a chassis switch with slots, where each switch in the stack represents a slot in the chassis.

Comment: "0/3-1/3" is not remotely the same as "0/3, 1/2-3". How many ports are there on slot 0? The former would change 0/3, 0/4, 0/5, ... 0/48 (48 port module), 1/1, 1/2, and 1/3. Obviously not the 3 ports you want. Which is why no IOS I'm aware of allows ranges to cross modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. After all, you could swap a module for a larger one and then `0/3-1/3` would mean something else...